# Compile custom directive before ui-bootstrap directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create my own directive for a datepicker so when the page is opened on a mobile device the input type change to `type="date"` and the native datepicker gets displayed instead of the ui-bootstrap datepicker which I still will be showing on desktop.

I want my directive to be compiled first so inside the `compile` function of my directive I be able to remove the ui-bootstrap datepicker directive and this one doesn't get compiled.

Is there a way to do this? I already tried setting `priority:9999` on my directive but still the ui-bootstrap directive gets compiled first.

I'm trying something like this right now:

```
<input type="text"
        ng-model="model.date"
        ng-click="datepicker.open = true"
        my-directive
        datepicker-popup="{{datepicker.format}}"
        datepicker-options="datepicker.options"
        is-open="datepicker.open"
        min-date="datepicker.minDate">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Angular directive priority starts from 0 (meaning the most important). So if you want your directive to be executed first you will need to specify

```
priority: 0
```

Comment: Setting `priority:0` did make my directive to compile first, however, even when I remove the ui-bootstrap directive from the input inside my directive's `compile` function the link function of the ui-bootstrap directive still executes so I still have that problem. I will mark this as correct although I couldn't solve my issue.

Comment: NOTE: Well, maybe this answer is old and things have changed but now we can precise that with priority 0 your directive will be executed last. Now the priorities with the HIGHEST value are executed first: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/docs/api/ng/service/$compile